# Align/Array equation - explain the options

Tags: align, amsmath, arrays, overset

I have searched and found a solution to a problem I had here: [Horizontal alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208960/horizontally-aligning-equations-with-overset-text), but now I have a follow-up question (and can't comment there because I have little reputation):

The code in the answer is

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
BEFORE
\begin{equation*}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5} % mimic wider spacing of align environment
\begin{array}{@{} r@{}c@{}l @{}}
   V & \overset{\textnormal{def}}{=}     & R(\delta) \\
     & \overset{ \{ 1.2.3 \} }{=} & \delta(a) R(a)
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
```

and this looks nice. However, when I remove all the `@{}` things, it looks different:

```
AFTER
\begin{equation*}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{array}{rcl}
   V & \overset{\textnormal{def}}{=}     & R(\delta) \\
     & \overset{ \{ 1.2.3 \} }{=} & \delta(a) R(a)
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
```

What do the `@{}` mean? Can you explain to me where the difference lies? I thought, only `\begin{array}{rcl}` would suffice to get the exact same output.

Picture:

[image: Picture_of_Code]

Comment: Between two columns there is always some space; with `@{...}` you tell LaTeX to place `...` between the two columns, instead of the usual space. So `@{}` means: put nothing (not even the space).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be better to use an environment designed for aligning displayed equations such as `align` from `amsmath` (which would set the display in display math mode and put the right space around the `=`.

`array` is designed for matrices and sets its content in inline math mode and is not optimised for aligning a single equation.

```
\begin{array}{rcl}
```

means a three column table but each column has `\tabcolsep` space (padding) either side so there is `2\tabcolsep` between each column.
`@{hello}` *replaces* the tabcolsep by the supplied text so this would write `hello` in each row.  so `@{}` has the effect of removing the `2\tabcolsep` space.

So `r@{}c@{}l` gives tighter spacing but neither gives the same space as an `=` normally gets in infix position compare with

```
\begin{align*}
   V & \overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}      R(\delta) \\
     & \overset{ \{ 1.2.3 \} }{=}  \delta(a) R(a)
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Wonderful. I did not use align because even though it's what I originally wanted to use, I wanted both the equal signs to be aligned vertically while not leaving too much space to their left and right. Searching for similar questions here led me to the answer which I followed up with my question.