# Multiple lines of text within a TikZ node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, math-mode, align, environments

I want to write multiple lines of text within a TikZ rectangle. This is how I did it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0, 0) [rectangle,draw,minimum size=2cm] {
    \begin{tabular}{c} \( a^2 \) \\ \( b^2 \) \end{tabular}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This works fine. But I want to understand why using another environment, such as, `align*` environment or displayed math does not work well like the `tabular` environment does.

For example, the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0, 0) [rectangle,draw,minimum size=2cm] {
    \begin{align*} a^2 \\ b^2 \end{align*}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

leads to the following error.

```
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.8     \begin{align*} a^2 \\ b^2 \end{align*}
```

The following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0, 0) [rectangle,draw,minimum size=2cm] {
    \[ a^2 \]
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

leads to the following error.

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.8     \[ a^
             2 \]
```

Here are my questions:

1. Why is special about `tabular` environment (compared to `align*` or displayed math) that makes it possible to use it as text within a node?
2. What do the `Missing \endgroup inserted` or `Missing $ inserted` errors mean?

Comment: Can't really answer your questions properly, but try setting `text width=5cm`.

Comment: It also works with `$\begin{array}{c} a^2 \\ b^2 \end{array}$`

Comment: Tabular is only as wide as it needs to be, but align fills the whole page.  Except that, unless you specify `text width` a node has nothing to fill.  Note that using `text width` is equivalent to putting the contents into a `\parbox`.

Comment: Regarding your question on the error with `\[ a^2 \]`, try changing it by `$a^2$` and the error dissapears. Somehow, math delimiters `\[ ... \]` are not allowed inside `TikZ`.

Comment: Did you find a solution after the answers posted or links?

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using `\shortstack[position]{... \\ ... \\ ...}`

> The \shortstack command produces a stack of objects. The valid
>   positions are:
>
> - r Moves the objects to the right of the stack
> - l Moves the objects to the left of the stack
> - c Moves the objects to the center of the stack (default)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

Using ``shortstack'' \\

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0, 0) [rectangle,draw,minimum size=2cm] {
\shortstack{$a^2$\\$b^2$}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) For sportmanship and for explanation. Someone downvoted both answers for some reason at the moment they marked it as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array` or `alined` environments

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

Using ``array'' \\

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0, 0) [rectangle,draw,minimum size=2cm] {
$\begin{array}{c} a^2 \\ b^2 \end{array}$
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\bigskip

Using ``aligned'' \\

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0, 0) [rectangle,draw,minimum size=2cm] {
$\begin{aligned} a^2 \\ b^2 \end{aligned}$
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And regarding your concerns about using one environment or another, I found some important information about it on answers of the following questions

> 1.[Align/Array equation - explain the options](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287635/align-array-equation-explain-the-options/287639)
>   **Answer** "array is designed for matrices and sets its content in inline math mode and is not optimised for aligning a single equation." -@David Carlisle
>
> 2.[Aligned equations inside of TikZ node.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1342/aligned-equations-inside-of-tikz-node) 
>   **Comment** "align is displayed, set off normal text and centered. Here it requires a minipage environment or \parbox, so it needs specifying a width. At least for the centering." – @Stefan Kottwitz

Comment: Do you know the answer to the two questions I have asked in my question?

Comment: @LoneLearner Unfortunately not. My knowledge in LaTeX is limited at that level and these such of things are very profound for me, I have to say. However, surfing into TeX.SE I have found many interensting answers that could be a good starting point for those concerns of yours. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40492/what-are-the-differences-between-align-equation-and-displaymath

Comment: Another ones https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95402/what-is-the-difference-between-aligned-in-displayed-mode-and-starred-align, among others, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401201/difference-between-align-and-alignedt... among others

Comment: @LoneLearner Someone has downvoted my answer and Flavs's too. I've just noticed that your question has been marked as duplicate as well.